# Labview : numbering color box array

Tags: arrays, labview

I have a color box array as below.

[image]

Now, I want to do numbering the array as below picture.

[image]

In order to do numbering, I just put texts on the array elements, manually.

I would like to do numbering automatically.

Can anyone give me a solution how to do numbering the array elements automatically?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add 2D numerical array. Resize it to have a size of the color box, make it transparent and show there what I wanted.

[image]

Please download example code from my dropbox (LV 15): https://www.dropbox.com/s/wevy0sgqnhgvh8p/Example%20on%20color%20box.vi?dl=0

and LV11:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zmrg66fai8cg3w6/Example%20on%20color%20box_11.vi?dl=0

Comment: Welcome, I think this is the simplest way

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a different approach.
1) Build a cluster containing both color box and a transparent number indicator
2) Put the cluster in a 2D array
Make a typedef of the cluster if you want.

In this way you can easily play with colors and numbers all around your program.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is another great idea~  Thank you very much!